# Cannot resolve constructor in Firebase list adapter

Tags: android, listview, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebaseui

Here is my code and I cannot figure out what is causing it to throw a cannot resolve constructor error. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import com.firebase.ui.FirebaseListAdapter;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
public class Home extends AppCompatActivity {

private FirebaseDatabase mFirebaseRef;
FirebaseListAdapter<ChatMessage> mListAdapter;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);

    final ListView listView = (ListView) this.findViewById(android.R.id.list);
```

my error starts here under (this,

```
    mListAdapter = new FirebaseListAdapter<ChatMessage>(this, ChatMessage.class,
            android.R.layout.two_line_list_item, mFirebaseRef) {
        @Override
        protected void populateView(View v, ChatMessage model, int position) {
            ((TextView)v.findViewById(android.R.id.text1)).setText(model.getName());
            ((TextView)v.findViewById(android.R.id.text2)).setText(model.getText());
        }
    };
    listView.setAdapter(mListAdapter);



    };
}
```

Dependencies:

```
 compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.0'
 compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.1'
 compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:10.0.1'
 compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:10.2.0'
 compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:10.2.0'
 compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:10.2.0'
 compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:10.2.0'
 compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:10.2.0'
 compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.3.0'
 compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui:0.3.1'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be importing:

```
com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseListAdapter
```

instead of:

```
com.firebase.ui.FirebaseListAdapter
```

Also make these changes to your build.gradle dependencies:

```
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:10.2.0'
compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui:1.2.0'
```

The table of Firebase UI compatible versions is in [the documentation](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android#compatibility-with-firebase--google-play-services-libraries).

Comment: when I try this I get the error cannot resolve symbol FirebaseListAdapter

Comment: compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.0'
 compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.1'
 compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:10.0.1'
 compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:10.2.0'
 compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:10.2.0'
 compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:10.2.0'
 compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:10.2.0'
 compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:10.2.0'
 compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.3.0'
 compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui:0.3.1'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

Comment: When I try to make the change in the build.gradle dependencies. i get the message Error:Failed to resolve: com.twitter.sdk.android:twitter:2.3.0

Comment: @JasonOliver: Make the change to the project build.gradle specified [here](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/blob/master/auth/README.md#configuration) to add the Fabric repository.